# What Titles and Rewards can be earned from the Chocobo Racing minigame?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

FFXIII-2 has a Chocobo racing minigame.

What Titles and Rewards can I get by Chocobo racing and what must I do to achieve them?

What are the rewards for each race?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have unlocked some, but not all of these, so I am going to cite some sources that complete what I know. Below are the Titles, Rewards (rare Adornments), and the unlock conditions for each that can be confirmed on [G4TV's](http://www.g4tv.com/thefeed/blog/post/720524/final-fantasy-13-2-chocobo-racing-guide/) racing guide (I moved some things around to make it easier to read). You can obtain Titles multiple times over different careers, the prize is a one-time bonus however.

```
Title Name              |        Reward            | Unlock Condition
-------------------------------------------------------------
Victorious              | Train Conductor Cap      | Win five races in a single career
Speedster               | Electric Guitar          | Demonstrate speed in a short race
Fortitude               | Lebreau's Violet Tattoo  | Win an 1,800m race
Underdog                | Ripe Apple               | Win a race where your Chocobo is not among the favorites
Trooper                 | Frying Pan               | Compete in 20 races in a single career
Moneybags               | Halo                     | Win 3,000 coins in a career
Bird on Fire            | Red Chocobo Chick        | Win 10 consecutive races
Derby Champ             | Blue Moogle Bobble       | Win all races with the "Derby" suffix in a single career
All-Rounder             | Tropical Tree            | Win a 600m, 1200m, and 1800m race during a single carrer
Super Sleuth            | Crown                    | Win all ten Secret races in a single career
Grade-Getter            | Tonberry Figurine        | Win all ten Graded races in a single career
King of Cocoon          | Bronze Medal             | Win all Cocoon Class races in one career
Monster Hunter          | Silver Medal             | Win all Monster Class races in one career
Weaponmeister           | Gold Medal               | Win all Weapon Class races in one career
Guardian Eliminator     | Mark of Lindzei          | Win all Guardian Class races in one career
Supreme Fal'Cie Chocobo | Mark of Etro             | Win all Fal'Cie Class races in one career
```

This is the list of all of the races, Coin Rewards, and Item Rewards completed with a post on [NeoSeeker](http://finalfantasy.neoseeker.com/wiki/Chocobo%20Racing%20%28FFXIII-2%29) (I added some additional information that I recorded from the game).

```
Race Name               | Distance |  Class   | Coins | Reward
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hanging Edge Classic    |   600m   |  Cocoon  |   30  | Potion
Bodhum Derby            |  1200m   |  Cocoon  |   30  | Potion
Vile Peaks Classic      |   600m   |  Cocoon  |   30  | Chocoboost
Bresha Classic          |  1200m   |  Cocoon  |   30  | Shuffle
Gapra Classic           |  1200m   |  Cocoon  |   30  | Shuffle
Palumpolum Cup          |   600m   |  Cocoon  |   30  | Power Bolt
Euride Stakes           |  1200m   |  Cocoon  |   30  | Mana Bolt
Nautilus Derby          |   600m   |  Cocoon  |   60  | Witch's Bracelet
Sanctum Special         |  1200m   |  Cocoon  |   60  | Zealot's Amulet
Orphan's Cup            |   600m   |  Cocoon  |   60  | Cute Cactuar Figurine; Power Droplet
Fifth Ark Cup           |  1200m   |  Cocoon  |   60  | Guard's Ravager Badge; Mana Droplet
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Goblin Derby            |   600m   |  Monster |   60  | Librascope
Malboro Classic         |  1200m   |  Monster |   60  | Librascope
Flan Stakes             |   600m   |  Monster |   60  | Chocoboost
Sahagin Derby           |  1200m   |  Monster |   60  | Chocoboost
Bomb Classic            |   600m   |  Monster |   60  | Shuffle (Common)
Garchimacera Cup        |  1200m   |  Monster |   60  | Shuffle (Common)
Adamantoise Classic     |   600m   |  Monster |   60  | Vitality Droplet
Ochu Classic            |  1200m   |  Monster |   60  | Vitality Bolt
Behemoth Special        |   600m   |  Monster |   80  | Silver Bangle
Ahriman Cup             |  1200m   |  Monster |   80  | Auric Amulet
Tonberry Cup            |   600m   |  Monster |   80  | Cie'th Wing; Power Droplet
Cactuar Cup             |  1200m   |  Monster |   80  | Piolet's Badge; Mana Droplet
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Blazefire Saber Classic |   600m   |  Weapon  |   80  | Phoenix Down
Durandal Cup            |  1200m   |  Weapon  |   80  | Phoenix Down
Altairs Stakes          |   600m   |  Weapon  |   80  | Chocobull
Pleiades Classic        |  1200m   |  Weapon  |   80  | Chocobull
Wild Bear Derby         |   600m   |  Weapon  |   80  | Shuffle (Graded)
Hawkeye Derby           |  1200m   |  Weapon  |   80  | Shuffle (Graded)
Airwing Cup             |   600m   |  Weapon  |   80  | Power Chip
Binding Rod Classic     |  1200m   |  Weapon  |   80  | Mana Chip
Gungnir Special         |   600m   |  Weapon  |  160  | Durable Warding Talisman
Partisan Stakes         |  1200m   |  Weapon  |  160  | Pain Dampener
Omega Weapon Cup        |   600m   |  Weapon  |  160  | Mog Figurine; Potent Droplet
Nirvana Cup             |  1200m   |  Weapon  |  160  | Cactuar Figurine; Potent Droplet
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Manasvin Cup            |   600m   | Guardian |  160  | Elixir
Myrmidon Derby          |  1200m   | Guardian |  160  | Elixir
Garuda Stakes           |   600m   | Guardian |  160  | Chocobull
Dreadnought Special     |  1200m   | Guardian |  160  | Chocobull
Aster Cup               |   600m   | Guardian |  160  | Vitality Sliver
Enki Enlil Classic      |  1200m   | Guardian |  160  | Vitality Chip
Ushumgal Derby          |   600m   | Guardian |  160  | Adamantite
Havoc Stakes            |  1200m   | Guardian |  160  | Dark Matter
Kalavinka Classic       |   600m   | Guardian |  320  | Nagaraja
Proudclad Classic       |  1200m   | Guardian |  320  | The Tower
Undying Cup             |   600m   | Guardian |  320  | Onion Knight's Helm; Power Sliver
Shaolong Gui Cup        |  1200m   | Guardian |  320  | White Chocobo Figurine; Mana Sliver
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Phoenix Cup             |   600m   | Fal'Cie  |  320  | Potent Sliver
Kujata Classic          |  1200m   | Fal'Cie  |  320  | Potent Sliver
Carbuncle Classic       |   600m   | Fal'Cie  |  320  | Power Orb
Anima Stakes            |  1200m   | Fal'Cie  |  320  | Mana Orb
Atomos Derby            |   600m   | Fal'Cie  |  320  | Vitality Orb
Bismarck Cup            |  1200m   | Fal'Cie  |  320  | Bloodguard
Dahaka Stakes           |   600m   | Fal'Cie  |  320  | Collector Catalog
Titan Classic           |  1200m   | Fal'Cie  |  320  | Potent Sliver
Eden Stakes             |   600m   | Fal'Cie  |  480  | Entite Ring
Orphan Derby            |  1800m   | Fal'Cie  |  480  | Potent Orb
Lindzei Cup             |   600m   | Fal'Cie  |  480  | Canned Sheep Logo; Potent Orb
Pulse Cup               |  1800m   | Fal'Cie  |  480  | Canned Coyo Logo; Potent Orb
```